# CSS selector to check that attribute does not contain both values

Tags: css, pseudo-class

I have a pretty odd CSS problem I want to solve.

I'm looking for any html element which does *not* have `display: none` (in any of its valid forms) inline in a `style` attribute.

Some examples:

- `<foo style="display:none" />`
- `<foo style="display: none" />`
- `<foo style="display : none" />`
- `<foo style="display  :   none" />`
- `<foo style="bar:baz; display:none" />`

I've been tinkering with the [`:not()` *negation* pseudo-class](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/not/) but the following selector is apparently invalid:

```
:not([style*='display'][style*='none'])
```

*It doesn't look like you can combine other selectors within a single `not()`*

I know that even if it worked, this could potentially create false positives for things like `<foo style="border: none; display: inline" />`, but I'm somewhat OK with that.

**So... is there any way to do what I want aside from hard-coding a bunch of the variations?**

*I really don't want to resort to this:*

```
:not([style*='display:none']):not([style*='display :none']):not([style*='display: none']:not([style*='display : none']):not([style*='display:  none'])...
```

#### Update:

The selector suggested in the comments (`:not([style*=display]):not([style*=none])`) will not actually work for me

Consider the following:

1. `<p></p>`
2. `<p style=""></p>`
3. `<p style="border: none;"></p>`
4. `<p style="border: none;"></p>`
5. `<p style="display: inline;"></p>`
6. `<p style="border: none; display: inline"></p>`
7. `<p style="display: none;"></p>`
8. `<p style="display   : none;"></p>`
9. `<p style="display   :none;"></p>`

`:not([style*=display]):not([style*=none])` will only select the first 2 `p`'s.

I want it to select the first 6 (or top 5 if thats the best I can get)!

Comment: `:not([style*=display]):not([style*=none])`?

Comment: @user2864740 That would work, but then it would select `<foo style="border: none; display: inline" />` .. as he already pointed out.

Comment: @JoshCrozier The OP is "somewhat OK with that." Although this feels like a messy [ab]use of selectors..

Comment: update: I don't think it will work actually.. See pending update

Comment: Try `:not([style*=display]), :not([style*=none])`. Remember that `!(a AND b) === !a OR !b`

Comment: @Pumbaa80 if you put that as an answer, I think you got it. A shame that in my use case (a bit more complicated than the question) this will make the code much more verbose, but I imagine this is the only correct approach!

Comment: What CSS properties do you want to apply to these selected elements?

Comment: @misterManSam its actually for use in a pretty complex Selenium-based browser automation project... I know it seems weird I'd need to do this, but its too lengthy of an explanation for my fingers to type at present ;-)

Answer (score 44, accepted):

As you mentioned, you want something equivalent to `:not([style*='display'][style*='none'])`, which is invalid in CSS, since `:not()` allows no combined selectors.

The laws of logic help us out here. Remember that `!(a AND b) == !a OR !b`, so we can write

```
:not([style*='display']), :not([style*='none'])
```

since in CSS, `a, b` matches elements that satisfy selector `a` OR selector `b`.

Again, as said in the question, this does not take the order of the words into consideration. The latter is impossible in CSS, since none of the [CSS attribute selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/#attribute-selectors) consider word order.

Comment: Love the boolean algebra. Thanks!

Answer (score 8):

It would clearly be better to do this with JavaScript... but here is one possible CSS solution:

```
p:not([style*=display]):not([style*=none]),
p[style*=display]:not([style*=none]),
p[style*=none]:not([style*=display]),
p[style*=border][style*=none] {
    color: red;
}
```

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/g4z79omh/)

As you can see, it is a little tedious. It covers a majority of cases, including the ones you listed. The more cases you want to cover, the more selectors you would need.

Comment: I gave @Pumbaa80 the checkmark on this one, although I think yours is technically more *correct*. He got in there 1st (in the comments) and his vibes a little bit more with my *actual* use case.

Answer (score 0):

There is no clean solution for this exact problem without javascript.

**I suggest the following:** 
If possible remove the usage of `style="display:none;"` and use a css-class like `class="hide"`

**If this is not possible:**  
You could add something like this into your javascript:

```js
function addHiddenClass( selector, cssClass){
    document.querySelectorAll(selector).forEach(node => { 
        if( getComputedStyle(node).display !== 'none') {
            return;
        }
        node.classList.add(cssClass);
    });
}
```

you could apply this then to the form whenever it is rendered:

```js
addHiddenClass('.your-form input,.your-form select,.your-form textarea','hidden');
```