# Extract links from list of urls that DO NOT contain 'target="_blank"' with Python

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have code that extracts links from a list of urls (and pairs them with the url they were extracted from), but I would like to alter it to grab only links on those pages that DO NOT contain target="_blank"

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

list_urls = ["https://example.com/1/","https://example.com/2/","https://example.com/3/"]
pagelinks = []

for url in list_urls:
    browser.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,"html.parser")

for line in soup.find_all('a'):
   href = line.get('href')
   pagelinks.append([url, href])

df = pd.DataFrame(pagelinks, columns=["from", "to"])
```

Comment: This can probably help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25676053/css-selector-to-check-that-attribute-does-not-contain-both-values

Comment: Change you last loop to `for line in soup.select('a:not([target="_blank"])'):`.

Comment: That did the trick– thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd

list_urls = ["https://example.com/1/","https://example.com/2/","https://example.com/3/"]
pagelinks = []

for url in list_urls:
    browser.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(browser.page_source,"html.parser")

    for line in soup.find_all('a'):
        if not line.get('target') == '_blank':
           href = line.get('href')
           pagelinks.append([url, href])

df = pd.DataFrame(pagelinks, columns=["from", "to"])
```